# How do you deploy a React App with an ExpressJS proxy server on GitHub Pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have seen videos on how to deploy an React App onto GitHub Pages, but I wonder how do I also deploy my ExpressJS proxy server that is used to handle API fetching for the React App?

The folder looks like this:

[image]

So normally I would start my proxy server first by typing npm start in the terminal. Then open up another terminal and cd to the client directory and type npm start to start my React App.

My client folder:

[image]

Comment: gh-pages is a static host. I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I deploy a react app with a node backend on GitHub Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620311/how-can-i-deploy-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-on-github-pages)